# Adding GLFW as a static library to CLion with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clion, glfw

i'm trying to add GLFW to my project as a static library and I cannot get it to work, after combing through hours of tutorials and websites. This is currently what my CMakeLists looks like and the file structure.

[image]

Comment: Please, add to the question post the code and the error message in the **textual** form, not a an *image*. This is a requirement of Stack Overflow, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Archaic glfw)
```

Or you can just put glfw source folder into your project, and use `add_subdirectory(glfwFolder)`

Comment: Just results in an error stating that there isn't a package configuration file provided or it cannot be found.

Comment: @GrantUpson with `add_subdirectory()` the same?